# Apply jquery to a code inserted with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, innerhtml

I have this line of code which is inserted via JS when the localDB is ready.

```
    //
    boxOne = document.getElementById("box1");
    content = '<button data-icon="delete">Delete</button>';
    boxOne.innerHTML = content;
    //
```

The problem with this code is that mobilejquery should read `data-icon="delete"` and add the class's for the icon to appear but its not doing that.
I can simply add the class's manually by my self but this is also causing me trouble when I am trying to apply a validation library to a form that is inserted by JS the validation wont work.
So how can I make jquery & any library that I use Reads this inserted JS code.

Comment: boxone.innerHTML = content?

Comment: which jqm version are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The other answers show you how to add the button, but not how to get jQuery Mobile to enhance it.

If you are using jQM 1.4, call `enhanceWithin()` on the container:

```
var content = '<button data-icon="delete">Delete</button>';
$("#box1").append(content).enhanceWithin();
```

If you are using 1.3, call `button()` on the button object:

```
var content = '<button data-icon="delete">Delete</button>';
$("#box1").append(content);
$("#box1 button").button();
```

NOTE: in my example I use `append()` to add the content, you can still use `html()` if you prefer.

Comment: That solved it many thanks
<code>$("#box1").html(content).enhanceWithin();</code>
thats did it form me I am using this code inside a for loop BTW

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean to put `content` inside `boxOne`. As it stands your trying to insert a DOM object (itself) into the `innerHTML`:

```
boxOne.innerHTML = content;
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/oGeez/54DdB/)

Or, since it's available to you, just use jQuery:

```
$btn = $('<button/>',{text:'Delete','data-icon':'delete'});
$('#box1').html($btn);
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/oGeez/54DdB/1/)

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery, you can use **[html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/)**:

```
$('#box1').html('<button data-icon="delete">Delete</button>');
```